# How can i find z-notation compiler or parser or interpreter?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter, z-notation

I should find z notation parser or compiler.  Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Community Z Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/czt/?source=navbar).

> Community Z Tools Project (CZT): Tools for editing, typechecking and
>   animating Z specifications and related notations. Includes a Java
>   framework for building formal methods tools.